# install4j +web service call for authentication

Tags: windows-installer, install4j

I am looking for a windows installer for a java application. It should support custom screen where I can ask for license key to the user. License key will be validated online through a `SOAP//REST` service.
Can anybody tell me if this is possible and which installer is best suited for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have marked the question with [install4j](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html), which is a solution that allows you to define a custom screen, see the [documentation](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/helptopics/concepts/formScreens.html) for more information.

Validating with SOAP/REST will require custom code. You can add required libraries on the Installer->Custom code & Resources tab and add a "Run script" action to enter the Java code directly in the install4j IDE.

Disclaimer: My company develops install4j.

Answer (score 0):

I think you Should look at the Oracle Universal Installer
[Check this.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/winsoft-098398.html)